# How does one get the keepalive.aspx to work over SSL?

Tags: configuration, security

Is there a way to get Sitecore to accept the SSL cert or are we required to disable HTTPS on those directories?

```
ManagedPoolThread #14 12:46:43 ERROR Exception in UrlAgent (url: /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Comment: Update: I was able to work around this by turning off the forced https to the directory and recycling the app pool.  Does not "answer" or "fix" the issue but is an acceptable work around for now.

Answer (score 4):

I've had success in the past by fully-qualifying the UrlAgent's parameter with the full host name, though I'm not familiar with the specific error you're displaying.

Example:

```xml
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
 <param desc="url">https://www.myapplication.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
 <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

Comment: This is the same syntax we are using with no problem.  First, make sure your keepalive.aspx page is actually accessible with a 200 response.   A 301/302 redirect -- due to URL rewrite rules -- might cause some issues.   Make sure that you have a valid cert, and not that Self-Signed Certs can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: @derek-c, I've tried that too.  With or without the base domain.  Doesn't seem to change the outcome.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code, good thoughts.  I checked those same things too.  SSL cert is a valid production cert.  I also double verified that the directory is open from any IIS Rewrite rules.  Starting to wonder if there is something configured at the server level as to what encryption levels (tls1, tls12, ssl3, etc) it defaults acceptance to.

Comment: Have you tried opening up a browser window from the server and hitting that URL via the browser?

Comment: @ben-lipson, it renders a response just fine thru a browser.  Guessing something in the browser is accepting the security settings where as the code isn't.  Something like this: System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: A bit older, but check out this: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/

Comment: and see comment #5 here (where they indicated it was caused by the load balancer) https://answers.coveo.com/questions/6225/installing-coveo-for-sitecore-diagnostic-page-error